# Passing a 1D array (single column of a Range object) to .NET to manipulate it without loops and returning it back to VBA

Tags: c#, performance, array, vba, com

## Background

Kind of a follow up - slightly related to [my other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683815/how-to-pass-an-array-range-value-to-a-native-net-type-without-looping).

I thought that if *somehow* I find a way in VBA to pass a single column to .NET and convert it to a native .NET type then I could finally overcome the mystery of explicitly looping on objects via COM (*which is super slow as we all know*). I'd then be able to use all the [cool stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) and not worry about constantly looping through `Excel.Range` object.

Please note: this is all about a **single column** not an `object[,]`.

## VBA side of things

It turns out in VBA you can get a 1D array like this:

[image]

## .NET Compatibility

Sample `.tlb/.dll` library in C# - [click here to get an idea](http://vba4all.com/how-to-securely-store-my-connection-string/)

It comes down to one method really:

```
public object Deduplicate1DArray(object arr)
{
    Array column = (Array)arr; // converts assumed/expected 1d array to System.Array
    List<string> list = column.OfType<string>().ToList(); // generic list to use the cool stuff 
    column = list.Distinct<string>().ToArray(); // convert back to match the type
    return column;
}
```

So from all the research I have done I thought that passing the 1d from VBA to .NET as `object` type is the way to go. If you know/experienced a better way (like passing the `Excel.Range` please share).

A successful conversion to a native .NET `System.Array` is possible which is just sweet because an `Array` can easily be converted to a generic `List<string>` which gives me access to all the [cool stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx).

So at this point I am not relying any longer on VBA to manipulate that `Range` and I can do amazing things that .NET allows me to on a generic `List<T>` type - I mean, how cool's that?

## Testing...

Attached references in the VBE to my `.tlb` and now I am able to use my library like

```
Dim c as new COMClass
```

Currently, I can test it like this:

```
Sub Main()

    Cells.ClearContents

    [A1] = "foo"
    [A2] = "boo"
    [A3] = "doo"
    [A4] = "goo"
    [A5] = "foo"

    Dim arr1D As Variant
    arr1D = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A5"))

    Dim c As New COMClass

    Dim noDuplicates As Variant
    noDuplicates = c.Deduplicate1DArray(arr1D)

    Range("B1").Resize(UBound(noDuplicates) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(noDuplicates)

End Sub
```

or

```
noDuplicates = Application.Transpose(c.Deduplicate1DArray(arr1D))
Range("B1").Resize(UBound(noDuplicates), 1) = noDuplicates
```

and that works as expected (*either way*)

[image]

## What bothers me...

1. A user of the library has to know and remember that the `COMClass.Deduplicate1DArray` needs to be passed a 1d array... therefore, in VBA they have to call the `Application.Transpose()` on the `Range` object to pass it properly. Things can get very .Net'ish if the user decides to do things like:

   ```
   noDuplicates = Application.Transpose(c.Deduplicate1DArray(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A5"))))
   ```

   or even worse

   ```
   Range("B1").Resize(SOME_BIG_NUMBER, 1) = Application.Transpose(c.Deduplicate1DArray(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A5"))))
   ```

   Anything I could do in either VBA or C# to improve that? Creating another wrapper or maybe just accepting the `Excel.Range` object and try to break it down to a 1d array in .NET?
2. This:

   ```
   Range("B1").Resize(10, 1) = c.Deduplicate1DArray(Range("A1:A5").Value)
   ```

   would have been *kind of good* or at least look sensible in terms of syntax but the problem is I shouldn't be `.Resizing` my `B1` - (*destination*) because I don't know how big the returned array after deduplication is going to be.

Any ideas of improving this are very welcome and if I have missed something please let me know I'll update with as much detail as I can.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know much about VBA or COM, so I'm going to focus on the single C# function:

If you know that all elements in the input sequence are of the same type, you should use [`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406), not `OfType`. `OfType` filters out all elements of the wrong type, which could easily hide bugs.

---

You don't need to call `ToList` to start using LINQ methods, they work on anything that's `IEnumerable<T>`, which includes the results of `Cast` and `OfType`.

---

When calling a method like `Distinct`, you don't need to specify the type parameter (`string` in your case), the compiler is able to infer it itself.

Answer (score 5):

I only know VBA so I'll focus on that bit of things.

You shouldn't be creating an array via worksheet. It's entirely unnecessary. Why not just:

```
Dim arr1D as Variant
arr1D = Array()
ReDim arr1D(1 to 5)

arr1D(1) = "foo"
arr1D(2) = "boo"
arr1D(3) = "doo"
arr1D(4) = "goo"
arr1D(5) = "foo"
```

You also don't need to transpose an array when printing to a column. The default first dimension of VBA arrays is already Vertical. Just:

```
Set printRng = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(Ubound(arr1D), 2))
printRng = arr1D
```

As far as your user having to know to pass only a 1D array, you've literally told them that in the function name. IMO, that's a sufficiently reasonable indication.